# SOAP action URL for authenticating sharepoint 2010? Can give idea for authentication

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Help me to authenticate sharepoint 2010 through SOAP action URL?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. this will give you some hints how to improve the question so that it can actually be answered.